# matplotlib 1.4.0 in PyQt5 application results in Segmentation Fault

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt5

Using matplotlib in PyQt5 RAD application causes Segmentation Fault after the Plot window is displayed correctly. System: Fedora 19 3.14.17, matplotlib-1.4.0.tar.gz was downloaded from matplotlib.org, and built on this system.

The application has a pushbutton that is connected to the function "doactionpushbutton", When clicked the function is entered and the plot with the label "Figure 1" is opened and is correct. The window remains open until the cursor is moved over the window at which time both the plot window and the main application window are closed and the segmentation fault message is returned.

Since I am new to mathplotlib, the question is "What am I doing wrong?"

Thanks in advance for any help.

***NOTE: I have provided a reduced size complete program that demonstrates the problem.***

The applicable code is listed below:

**Mainwindow**

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainwindow.ui'
#
# Created: Thu Aug 28 18:24:05 2014
#      by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.3.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 300)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 97, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 27))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

**Program**

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtWidgets
import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use('')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class Editor(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Editor, self).__init__()
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.doactionpushButton)

    def doactionpushButton(self):
        self.plot_it()

    def plot_it(self):
        # red dashes, blue squares and green triangles
        t = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)
        plt.plot(t, t, 'r--', t, t**2, 'bs', t, t**3, 'g^')
        plt.show(block=True)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Editor()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you simplify this to an example that does not use `Ui_MainWindow`.  As this stands, I can't run this example and hence don't know if the issue is on the mpl side or in code that we can't see.  I suspect the problem is that you also have pyqt4 set up and pyplot is starting up for pyqt4, hence things blow up.  try adding `import matplotlib` and `matplotlib.use('qt5agg')` before you import pyplot.

Comment: Thanks -- Tried the "import" and "use" you suggested.  
System responded with the following although the PyQt sites says PyQt4 and PyQt5 can live together. Will try to put together a more compact failing example.  
ValueError: Unrecognized backend string "qt5agg": valid strings are ['pgf', 'cairo', 'MacOSX', 'CocoaAgg', 'gdk', 'ps', 'GTKAgg', 'GTK', 'QtAgg', 'template', 'FltkAgg', 'emf', 'GTK3Cairo', 'GTK3Agg', 'WX', 'Qt4Agg', 'TkAgg', 'agg', 'svg', 'GTKCairo', 'WXAgg', 'pdf']

Comment: I suspect it it `'QtAgg'` then.

Comment: @tcaswell QtAgg wants me to install pyqt3. Tried that is there anyway I can specify pyqt5? I tried import PyQt5 but python seemed to pick up pyqt3 when I installed it.

Comment: @tcaswell Complete Code demonstrating the problem is in the original post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you install over top of an existing mpl installation?  I thought we got rid of all of the qt3 related stuff... We also only support qt5 with python3.

Comment: Crashes in Archlinux with python-matplotlib 1.4.0

Comment: I installed qt3 temporarily and got errors associated with qt3, I have since removed qt3.

Comment: I am still fighting the problem here. I have not found a work around solution.  Looking at the matplotlib source, it appears to have code associated with PyQt5. Using it in the interactive mode seems to work fine. Only when using it with PyQt5 does it cause the problem.

Comment: Will have to use another approach to do the plotting although I really like matplotlib.

Comment: Replaced matplotlib with master (1.5.x) and the problems experienced above are gone.  Thanks again to tcaswell for his attention to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading matplotlib-master.zip and installing it corrected the problem.  For some reason the version of matplotlib (1.4.0) did not have the correction that tcaswell had put in. 
Thanks to tcaswell for his help.